# Composer com XDEBUG - PHP

Tags: php, composer, xdebug

Eu tenho *XDEBUG* instalado no meu `PHP`. Nesse cenário, quando se faz uma instalação do composer recebo uma mensagem de erro sobre performance de runtime, segundo a foto abaixo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha pergunta é qual o alcance dessa queda de performance? Seria somente na execução do composer, quando estou fazendo download e instalando dependências ou na execução do `PHP` (que seria o caso mais grave)?

Aqui no site do [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#xdebug-impact-on-composer) temos a instrução de como desativar o *xdebug*, mas não fica muito claro se será algo permanente.

Alguém já teve esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O XDebug não esta instalado (habilitado) no Composer e sim no PHP, existem duas camadas básicas de uso do php, a web (que pode usar vários tipos de módulos) e a CLI (linha de comando), no caso o XDebug só vai lhe ser útil no modulo com Apache (como PHP-FPM, Apache2handler ou Fast-cgi) no composer ele é totalmente dispensável.

O XDebug é uma ferramenta para desenvolvimento, ou seja o composer não é desenvolvimento necessariamente, é gerenciador de pacotes, o desenvolvimento vai acontecer após instalar os pacotes.

Essa mensagem que aparece é só uma explicação que a performance pode ser afetada nas execuções PHP, geralmente a cada instalação via composer dependendo do pacote ou aplicação vai demorar mais, mas pode ser que você nem sinta isso, ou seja varia de pacote pra pacote.

No caso como esta usando Xampp então os arquivos de configuração são:

- `c:\xamp\apache\bin\php.ini` usado para o Apache, ou seja as configurações serão validas quando acessar `http://localhost/`
- `c:\xampp\php\php.ini` usado para CLI/CGI, ou seja se digitar no CMD `php script.php` serão usado essas configurações, no caso o composer usa o CLI.

Então abra e edite o `c:\xampp\php\php.ini` usando SublimeText ou Notepad++, não use o notepad.exe do Windows (conhecido como Bloco de notas) pois ele não reconhece as quebras de linhas, procure uma linha semelhante a:

```
zend_extension_ts="C:/xampp/php/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
```

ou (bem pouco provável):

```
extension="C:/xampp/php/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
```

E comente ela assim adicionando o `;` no começo:

```
;zend_extension_ts="C:/xampp/php/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
```

Note que isto são exemplos, se não encontrar usa o Ctrl+F no seu editor de texto (sublimetext ou notepad++) e digite `xdebug`, vai procurando até achar o `.dll`.

Como eu disse o XDebug não serve de nada para o `composer`, o XDebug é só usado no momento que você esta escrevendo os seus arquivos.

### Se não for Xampp

Pode ocorrer de estar usando outro facilitador de instalação do php+apache, neste caso pode ser que o php.ini para CLI e para Apache sejam os mesmo, neste caso você mesmo pode configurar o Apache para carregar um php.ini diferente, no caso copie o seu arquivo `php.ini` que esta na pasta da instalação do PHP para uma pasta qualquer diferente, de preferencia a pasta do apache (supondo que seja `C:\apache\`) e depois edite o arquivo chamado httpd.conf com sublimetext ou notepad++ (ou outro editor semelhante) e procure uma linha assim `PHPIniDir`, se o valor dela estiver diferente da local da instalação do php é porque já existe um php.ini somente para o apache e esse processo é dispensavel, mas se estiver algo como `C:\php\` ou `C:\wamp\php\` então troque o valor para apontar para o novo php.ini, por exemplo:

```
PHPIniDir "C:/apache/"
```

Desta maneira você terá um php.ini somente para o apache e outro somente para o PHP em modo CLI/CGI, como eu disse no php.ini para apache pode habilitar o XDebug e no php.ini que esta na mesma pasta que o php.exe você deve desabilitar o XDebug com os exemplos que citei anteriormente.

### Instalado via repositório (linux ou like-unix)

Em sistemas como linux as vezes a instalação do PHP e Apache são feitas via repositório e geralmente assim já existirá por padrão um php.ini para CLI e outro para Apache, geralmente o caminho é `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`, mas tem vezes que o local é diferente, pra isto você pode procurar usando o seguinte comando no terminal:

```
$ php -i |grep php\.ini
```

<sub>Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3057131/1518921</sub>

Ou se precisar de mais detalhes:

```
$ php --ini
```

<sub>Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3057131/1518921</sub>

Então abra o arquivo com seu editor de texto (por exemplo vim, gpedit, leafpad, etc) e procure uma linha que contenha algo semelhante a isto:

```
zend_extension="ext/php_xdebug.so"
```

Ou isto:

```
extension="ext/php_xdebug.so"
```

E comente ela adicionando `;` no começo, ficando algo semelhante a isto:

```
;zend_extension="ext/php_xdebug.so"
```

### Conclusão

Pronto, agora o Xdebug estará desabilitado para o composer, pois realmente é algo que não é necessário, note que apesar de usar Xdebug junto ao PHP com Apache, **ele só deverá** ser usado para desenvolvimento, no teu servidor de produção (quando colocar o site no ar para as pessoas usarem) deve sempre deixar desabilitado o XDebug no servidor online (ou seja fora da sua máquina), isso porque ele além de não servir de muita coisa no servidor de produção ele ainda consome muito afetando o desempenho.

Comment: Correto, como vc mesmo disse, eu só vou ter xdebug no ambiente de desenvolvimento, por isso não me preocupa na produção. Na verdade eu nem tenho xdebug no php da produção. A minha dúvida foi no ambiente de produção, o quanto seria afetado peloo xdebug. Mas já está claro. Valeu.