# Composer extremamente lento e inconsistente

Tags: php, framework, composer

A alguns dias estou tendo um problema em meu composer que não faz muito sentido(não possui uma falha/lógica padrão, os erros são quase que aleatórios), por isso não estou conseguindo resolver, o que acontece é o seguinte.

Possuo um mini framework, e estou atualizando ele conforme estou precisando dos recursos, os passos são os seguintes:

1 - Altero o framework.

2 - Faço o push no github.

3 - Atualizo o packagist.

4 - Atualizo o `composer` no projeto que estou utilizando ele (Nesta etapa está o problema)

Caso eu indique para atualizar apenas a dependencia em questão, funciona corretamente, porém, se eu dou o comando `'composer update'` ele remove algumas dependências (as vezes todas) e instala novamente, e ainda por cima não atualiza o `autoloader` se a pasta `'vendor/composer'` não for deletada, e pra complicar, esse processo do comando update está levando mais de 20 minutos, e originando diversos alertas como esse.

```
exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
```

Mas, essa atualização das dependências não são consistentes, ou seja, não são as mesmas que atualizam sempre, cada vez é uma diferente.

OBS:Verifiquei no repositório das dependências que atualizam, e a maioria não tem alteração no `github/gitlab` mas mesmo assim o `composer` identifica que a versão que eu possuo é diferente da versão disponível.

Lista de dependências que solicitam atualização sem terem sido modificadas com mais frequência:

PHPDocumentor (Essa é a que mais demora e as atualizações são inconsistentes)

Synfony

Doctrine

Guzzlehttp

robinherbots/jquery.inputmask (Essa atualiza 100% das vezes e demora muito)

cocur/slugify

components/jquery

zendframework

E quando cada uma desses dependências possuem outras dependências, as mesmas também são atualizadas 100%, demorando muito tempo pra concluir, quando não alerta erros e/ou não conclui.

E o segundo problema está na questão da atualização do `autoload` dentro de `vendor`.

Se o arquivo `composer.json` é atualizado para incluir algum `namespace` novo, e for dado comando update, ele faz todo o processo, indica sucesso, porém não inclui o novo `namespace` no `autoload`, pra que essa etapa funcione, eu preciso deletar a pasta `'vendor/composer'` dar o comando `'composer update'` e aguardar +- 20 minutos(ja chegou a mais de 40) para atualizar tudo e eu poder voltar a trabalhar.

Informações adicionais:

> Teste: SO Ubuntu 16.4
>
> Produção: SO Debian 7.
>
> PHP: 7. GIT: Ultima versão.
>
> Permissões das pastas 777.
>
> IDE: Netbeans 8.2
>
> Internet Banda Larga 50MB Estável.

composer.json

```
  {
    "name": "contabil app center",
    "description": "",
    "type": "Biblioteca",
    "license": "BSD-3",
    "version": "1.0",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Gabriel",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.8",  
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "slim/pdo": "~1.9",
        "cocur/slugify": "dev-master",
        "components/jquery": "~3.2.1",
        "wixel/gump": "dev-master",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2",
        "easy-cont/vidb": "dev-master",
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {

            "appModel\\": "model/app",
            "appView\\": "view/app",
            "appController\\": "controller/app",
            "appFinancialRestatement\\":"model/app/calculations/financial-calculations",
            "appFinancialIndices\\":"model/app/calculations/financial-calculations",
            "appDebitWorksheet\\":"model/app/calculations/financial-calculations",
            "appFIPE\\":"model/app/fipe",
            "phpToJs\\":"interactors",
            "siteModel\\": "model/site",
            "indexView\\": "view/site",
            "siteController\\": "controller/site"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Joga teu `composer.json` para gente ver o que pode estar ocorrendo. Mas, aparentimente pode ser algum erro em teu composer. Qual versão dele?

Comment: Adicionei o composer.json no final da resposta, estou usando a ultima versão, se não me engano é a 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possíveis causas de erro:

### 1. Problemas na rede:

Conforme a pergunta abaixo pode ser um problema com IPV6, acaso seja Linux, não sei se o problema ocorre em Windows:

- [Composer não instala pacotes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116420/3635)

Também pode ser um problema com o Firewall ou Proxy na rede, sendo um destes dois não tenho como formular uma resposta "padrão", porque cada rede pode funcionar de uma maneira.

### 2. Xdebug ou semelhante ativo no CLI

O composer é PHP em CLI (interface de linha de comando), usar o XDebug nele ou extensões semelhantes pode causar problemas do tipo, recomendo que crie um `php.ini` para o CLI e outro para o Apache (se for linux já é separado) e então no `php.ini` para CLI basta comentar a linha de todas possíveis extensões que usa para depurar como expliquei nesta resposta:

- [Composer com XDEBUG - PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135820/3635)

### 3. Composer desatualizado

Pode ser um bug da versão do `composer`, ou talvez era assim que funcionava em versões antigas, baixando tudo novamente, no caso primeiro pode verificar a versão atual do composer com o comando:

```
composer -V
```

> Nota: o `V` é em maiúsculo

Ou o comando:

```
composer -about
```

A versão mais atual é o `1.5.1`, se for inferior a isto é necessário atualizar, para isto use o comando:

```
composer self-update
```

Se o comando não funcionar é porque realmente deve estar usando uma **versão muito antiga**, então só irá conseguir atualizar manualmente, sendo Linux eu não posso afirmar aonde foi instalado por que isto é opção do usuário da máquina, se souber aonde esta o arquivo `composer.phar` remova ele e instale novamente:

Baixe o setup:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa0355160742ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

E então execute o setup:

```
php composer-setup.php
```

---

### Instalando composer globalmente no Linux

No linux o composer não é instalado globalmente, mas pode copiar mover manualmente, depois de baixar pode fazer isto conforme a resposta do [**Wallace**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118468/3635):

```
chmod +x composer.phar
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Ou conforme a resposta [**Daniel**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118489/3635) edite o `.bashrc` e adicionar:

```
alias composer=/a/pasta/onde/esta/conposer.phar
```

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63932/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-anthraxisbr).